# how to extract the table from database into .doc file using PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to extract or get the table from database into the .doc file, but i am facing one problem, the problem is that not getting the result in the tabular form into .doc file , it seems like a paragraph all the columns and their data scattered.

So kindly help me, how i can extract this table into a tabular form in the .doc file, i don't wish to extract table into the excel sheet or CSV sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create HTML pages with `.doc` extension. Simply create a html content which contains your table. It's possible to edit using MS Word too. But if you want to create old (or new) MS Office doc format, you will need a Windows server. Then you can use [COM class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) to access `word.application` instance and you can manipulate documents.